# How to match two .csv files and write on third file replacing data in file 2 with data from file 1

Tags: regex, linux, perl, bioinformatics, bioperl

I have 2 csv and text files, file 1 has 2 columns one with gene id and two with gene name,file 2 has many columns with part of the string in columns being gene id e.g gene id(genome) or pseudo gene id(genome). i want to compare each gene id in file 1 with each gene id in file 2 and replace the gene id in file 2 with the gene name in file 1 printing in file 3.

file 1;

```
SPAR5_0024, coA binding domain protein                    
SPAR5_0025, hypothetical protein                    
SPAR5_0026, hypothetical protein
```

file 2;

```
SPAR5_0024(72.AFAX01.1.gb) SPAR5_0026(72.AFAX01.1.gbff) SPAR5_0025(72.AFAX01.1.gbff)
```

desired output (file 3);

```
coA binding domain protein(72.AFAX01.1.gb) hypothetical protein(72.AFAX01.1.gbff) hypothetical protein(72.AFAX01.1.gbff)
```

with my code am getting an empty file 3

This is what am running;

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = "annot.txt";
my $file2 = "orthomcl.csv";
my $file3 = "combi.csv";

open (FILE1,"$file1") || die;
open (FILE2,"$file2") || die;
open (FILE3,">$file3") || die;


my @file1 = <FILE1>;
my @file2 = <FILE2>;


my %file1;
while ( my $value = <FILE1> ) {
    chomp $value;
    my @file1 = split /\s+/, $_;
    $file1{$value} = 1;
}

my %file2;
while (my $value = <FILE2>) {
    chomp $value;
    my @file2 = split /\s+/, $_;
    if ( $file1{ $value } ) {
        $file2 = $file1{ $file2 };
        print join( "\t" => @file2 ), $/;
    }
}

close (FILE1);
close (FILE2);
close (FILE3);
```

desired output (file 3)

```
coA binding domain protein(72.AFAX01.1.gb) hypothetical protein(72.AFAX01.1.gbff) hypothetical protein(72.AFAX01.1.gbff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary error is that

```
my @file1 = <FILE1>;

my @file2 = <FILE2>;
```

consume all data from the files, so that there's nothing left to read for the

```
while ( my $value = <FILE1> ) {
```

and

```
while (my $value = <FILE2>) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can insert the annotations from the first file `annot.txt` into the second file `orthomcl.csv`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my $map = read_annot();
    my ($regex) = map {qr /$_/} join '|', map {quotemeta} keys %$map;
    my $fn = 'orthomcl.csv';
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh;
    $str =~ s/($regex)/$map->{$1}/ge;
    save_combi( $str );
}

sub save_combi {
    my ( $str ) = @_;

    my $fn = 'combi.csv';
    open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh $str;
    close $fh;

    say "Saved: '$fn'";
}

sub read_annot {
    my $fn = 'annot.txt';
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my %map;
    while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my ( $key, $value ) = $line =~ /^(\S+),\s+(.*)$/;
        $value =~ s/\s+$//;
        if (defined $key) {
            $map{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
    return \%map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hakon. your code doesn't give me any results though.

Comment: Hi. Can you send me the input files you are using? Then I will have a look at it. My email is in my profile.